# Function overload not compatible with implementation

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out why some code I'm looking at is not working. I have a structure similar to this:

```js
function getValidity(x: "v1"): boolean;
function getValidity(x: "v2"): { a: number; b: number };
function getValidity(x: any) {
  if (x === 'v1') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return { a: 1, b: 2 };
  }
}
```

But I get the error

> This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)

[Looking at examples](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) I thought this would work, but I'm obviously missing something. What is it?

Comment: I guess the compiler is unable to infer the type returned by your implementation. You could mark it as `function getValidity(x: any):boolean|{ a: number; b: number } {`.

Comment: Or simply mark it as `any`, same way as in the example. Missing return type causes the error.

Comment: @ViktorGusev Thanks - useful information

Comment: @WiktorZychla many thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function getValidity(x: 'v1'): boolean;
function getValidity(x: 'v2'): { a: number; b: number };
function getValidity(x: 'v1' | 'v2'): boolean | { a: number; b: number } {
  if (x === 'v1') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return { a: 1, b: 2 };
  }
}

console.log(getValidity('v1'));
console.log(getValidity('v2'));
```

Comment: thanks for that - you may (or may not) want to consider adding some explanation for other people who find this

Comment: It's not clear why this is a solution. I don't get why the original code does work.